# Let $D(G)$ the conmutator subgroup of $G$. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $D(G)\subset H$ show $H$ is normal to $G$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $D(G)$  the  conmutator subgroup of $G$. If $H$  is a subgroup of $G$ such that $D(G)\subset H$ show $H$ is normal to $G$.

Please, I appreciate any help, since I have some ideas, but those are not clear.

Comment: What does $H$ look like in the quotient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you must prove is that for every $x \in G$ and $h \in H$, you have $xhx^{-1} \in H$. Now write $xhx^{-1} = xhx^{-1}h^{-1} \cdot h$. I used the "dot" before the last $h$ as a hint... what can you say about the RHS now? Does it bring to mind anything about $D(G)$, and the hypotheses that $D(G) \subset H$ and $H$ is a subgroup?

Comment: Thanks. I already  see  clearly  why $H$ must be normal to $G$